# Saving the file downloaded with the pytube library to the desired location

Tags: python, pytube

For some reason I don't understand, the codes do not work, strangely, I do not get an error, it just does not save where I want, it saves to the folder where the file is run.

```
af = input("Link:")
yt = YouTube(af, on_progress_callback=progress_callback)
stream = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
print(f"Downloading video to '{stream.default_filename}'")
pbar = tqdm(total=stream.filesize, unit="bytes")
path = stream.download()
#Download path
b = open("\Download", "w")
b.write(stream.download())
b.close()
pbar.close()
print(Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX+"Saved video to {}".format(path))
time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: I want to save it to Download file in my folder

Comment: I highly doubt `\Download` is a real absolute path on your machine

Comment: in my project folder have a \Download folder , ı wanted save to in my project folder \Download folder https://prnt.sc/1t0zcrm

Comment: Then `open('Download/' + stream.default_filename, 'w')`

Comment: You could also not use Python code, and just write a Windows batch script with `youtube-dl` https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl#how-do-i-put-downloads-into-a-specific-folder

Comment: Unfortunately it still save in the same place

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/7936093/2308683

Comment: no not help what ı am doing in there to doing

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include any new code you've tried. Basically, you need to provide the full path to the file name that you want to write to. You cannot open and write directly into a folder

Answer (score 0):

First, to save the file in a specific directory we need to create the directory, I will do this through this function

```
import sys, os    
def createDirectory(name):
    path = sys.path[0] # Take the complete directory to the location where the code is, you can substitute it to the place where you want to save the video.
    if not(os.path.isdir(f'{path}/{name}')): # Check if directory not exist
        path = os.path.join(sys.path[0], name) # Set the directory to the specified path and the name that was given to it
        os.mkdir(path) # Create a directory
```

After that we need to save the file in the newly created directory, for that within the "stream.download" in the parameter "output_path" we pass the total path to save and then the variable that contains the name of the newly created directory.

```
directoyName = 'Video'

createDirectory(directoyName)

path = sys.path[0] # Take the complete directory to the location where the code is, you can substitute it to the place where you want to save the video.

stream.download(output_path=f'{path}/{directoyName}') # Save the video in the newly created directory.
```

This way the file will be saved in the directory with the specified name.